# Visual Studio move code window from one side to the other

Tags: visual-studio

Usually, in VS 2015 I split my workspace in 2 windows, having side by side 2 files of code. Often want to move one code window to the other side. What I do is drag the window tab with the mouse from one side to the other. This is slower than if there was a shortcut to do it.

Is there a shortcut in VS 2015 to move code windows to next/previous code window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you right-click the file tab, there are options for "Move to Next Tab Group" and "Move to Previous Tab Group". This cuts it down to 2 clicks instead of a drag operation.

Then, you can go into Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and assign shortcut keys to both operations. They are listed as the commands **Window.MoveToNextTabGroup** and **Window.MoveToPreviousTabGroup**.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an option to cycle the tab between groups. So, if you move a tab to "Next", you can't move "Next" again to get it back to group 1, you have to move "Previous".

Comment: That suck a thousand donkeys... I spend three hours googling it and it seems that your statement is still valid... 6 years shy of a few months later... Embarrassing... I hold the standing war with all the VSC and Ryder dudes and this is not really helping.   :)